# I want to replace pandas with the csv module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I want to use the csv module instead of pandas for this program, how can I do that? Currently, I am not able to properly get pandas to install and work so I want to use the csv module.

This is my code:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import webbrowser

def sign_in(meetinglink):
    webbrowser.open(meetinglink)  
  
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/3021118/Applications/Meeting-Launcher/timings.csv')

while True:
    now = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
    if now in str(df['timings']):
        row = df.loc[df['timings'] == now]
        m_link = str(row.iloc[0,1])

        sign_in(m_link)
        time.sleep(10)
        print('MEETING JOINED!')
```

This is what timings.csv looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTPlT.png

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this -   Modify as applicable

```
import csv
with open("file_name.csv", "rt") as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"'):
         #your logic
```